# How would you organize or store your json data in a csv or database?

Tags: python, json, database, networking

Ok so I am dabbling with writing a python network scanner, probably been done a million times, but I am doing it for fun. I am only using it on my home network. The question is this, every scan I return a json formatted file that contains the results of my scan. Would you just dump this data to a flat file database or would you use sql of somesort? What formats do you think would be best for storing these fields? (sample data below).  Was also considering doing port lookup to find out what the port is normally used for. So that being said. What do you think would be the easiest but robust format to store the devices on my network in?

```
 [
    {
        "address": "10.10.10.204",
        "computer": "pixel-3-a",
        "mac_address": "3c:28:6d:09:88:ea",
        "net_status": "Alive",
        "open_ports": 0,
        "port_numbers": [],
        "scan_date_time": "2022.03.131628"
    },
    {
        "address": "10.10.10.252",
        "computer": "host-21",
        "mac_address": "18:31:bf:e5:cd:c8",
        "net_status": "Alive",
        "open_ports": 15,
        "port_numbers": [
            "80",
            "443"
        ],
        "scan_date_time": "2022.03.131628"
    },
    {
        "address": "10.10.10.209",
        "computer": "pixel-3-b",
        "mac_address": "dc:e5:5b:1d:9c:e7",
        "net_status": "Alive",
        "open_ports": 0,
        "port_numbers": [],
        "scan_date_time": "2022.03.131628"
    }    
]
```

Comment: Without knowing what you will use the data for, this is impossible to answer. And even if this was known, the answers are likely to be opinion-based.

Comment: I am going to keep record of the devices and alert myself when new MAC's and IP's are found on my network. I will be keeping a list of good\known hosts to reference and the others I will eventually find out what device it is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would store it as JSON in mysql.